# Yelp API Integration based on location

Tags: php

I am trying to integrate yelp api to search locations.I tried and succeed in searching based on name and location name.But I am not able to filter the results centered on a latitude and longitude.Every time the same latitude longitude values are same.I gave the values as parameter 'cll'. But the 'center' values are not changing to my input values.Is it possible to do this using yelp api ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am able to get the result from yelp.yelp has a parameter called 'll' where we can give latitude and longitude.This parameter will help to search based on location latitude and longitude.Please not that yelp will not take parameter 'll' along with parameter 'location' or 'cll' since they also indicate location.